# Some Images be on the top of the image cropper

Tags: flutter, image-cropper

When i used to upload image from camera some be on the top of image cropper

code

```
  try {
if (isItPickMenu) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source:
        imageSource); //todo if the user denied the permission 
ask him again.
} catch (error) {
print(error);
}
if (pickedFile != null) {
final croppedImage = await cropImage(
    cropStyle: CropStyle.rectangle,
    pickedImage: pickedFile,
    cropAspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 3.0, ratioY: 2.0));
if (croppedImage != null) {
  return croppedImage;
}
}
```

[image]

and Some works great

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the issue better and include some code snippets to understand the issue better

Comment: @KaushikChandru i added some code

Comment: That's a normal behaviour to show you how much part of the image will be cut from the original. Once you click on the tick mark on top right. It will crop to the portion that visible in the middle

Comment: @KaushikChandru i know that i mean from my question some images be on the top of this rectangle box and some images be below it why this happens

Comment: It is definitely not on top of it. Since your image is black and the overlay is grey it got merged. please click another photo

Comment: @KaushikChandru yes yes you are right, i was confused with the black color, thanks bro for your help